# Database printing different column related to method

Tags: python, excel, pandas, row

My question is to show the most popular game in 2019. I have the code for sorting which year and finding the max value but I cannot figure out how to get the Name of the game for this information. Please help :)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\imogen\Documents\IT\vgRatings.csv')

most_popular2019 = df[df['Year'] == 2019].max()['Critic_Score']
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
most_popular2019 = df.loc[df['Year'] == 2019, 'Critic_Score'].max()
```

For index by maximal values use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
idx = df.loc[df['Year'] == 2019, 'Critic_Score'].idxmax()
name = df.loc[idx, 'Name']
```

Comment: i keep getting an error message that name isnt defined

Comment: @imyGreene - oops, changed.